# Visual Studio 2017 Installation Issue

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2017 on my machine, that already has Visual Studio 2015 installed. But when I try to install I get following error:
[image: Visual Studio Installation Error]

And when I try to give alternate path to the file, it gives error: Wrong package.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a complete uninstall of both visual studio's, if you need vs studio 2015 make sure you install this before you install 2017.

One thing I know with most Microsoft software always install them in **year order** with no traces of other installations left behind, also I have found it is bad to install 64 bit and 32 bit versions together although I find that issue less as time goes on.

See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/

Answer (score 0):

[**First you can try to run this tool from Microsoft**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) and see if it cleans out broken installations. You might have to manually initiate the uninstalls for the packages that won't uninstall - see the quote below for a description from the user who actually ran the tool (I never did).

I believe this tool is Microsoft's replacement for the old MSI cleanup-tool based on <del>MsiZap.exe</del> that has been deprecated for quite some time. Remember to leave a comment if this fix works so others know.

---

This issue seems to have been discussed on MSDN as well: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ecc1495-de4d-432f-9886-94d28ced6dc9/vs-community-2017-installation-problems?forum=vssetup) (shortened link). Here is the core of it: "*... I used this tool to uninstall the packages that the vs_community 2017 installer was complaining it could not uninstall.  As I uninstalled the packages and retried the vs installer, I would hit another package that could not be uninstalled.  Eventually, after 4 or 5 packages were uninstalled, the installer completed successfully and it seems to work.* "

---

Just for reference: [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Comment: Also see this blog entry from Heath Stewart: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/09/01/cleaning-up-corrupt-visual-studio-instances/